# How to count selected records in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Assuming that I have records of New and Old students. What i would like to do is this

```
Count({StudentInformation.Surname}) Where {StudentInformation.Status} = "old"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create formula X:

```
if {StudentInformation.Status} = "old" then 1 else 0
```

Then you can sum over this formula:

```
sum({@X})
```